# Text adventure game problems with moving around with Directions

Tags: haskell

I have problems moving around my map in Haskell. If the player's input is e.g. `BackOff`, I need to change the current location to the new one, but i also need to check if there is a location.

I'm not sure how exactly to write the `move` function. I also want to show the player where they can move to from the current location (You can only move one space at a time.)

My first idea was to check if the input is `TurnLeft` for example, and reduce `Direction` so it gets to `West` (I assume I programmed it wrong) and increase so it gets to `East` and so on.

How do I check if the location the player wants to travel is available and how do I change location then?

```
location = "Fort Neugrad" -- the player starts in Fort Neugrad first

currentDirection = North -- the player faces north at first

data Direction = North | East | South | West deriving(Show, Eq, Enum)

data Movement = TurnLeft | TurnRight | Advance | BackOff deriving(Show)

type Location = String

type GameMap = [((Location, Direction), Location)]   -- First location is the     current location, second is the next location where the direction points to(Ive made a map but its to large to post it)

--move :: Movement -> Direction -> Location
--move m = case m of TurnLeft -> pred currentDirection
       --            TurnRight -> succ currentDirection
       --            Advance ->
       --            BackOff ->


filterAccess :: Location -> [Location]
filterAccess l = [ c | ((a,b), c) <- wonderland, a == l ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I see in your design is that you have global constants `location` and `currentDirection`.  This isn't compatible with the way that Haskell works: because Haskell is purely functional, you'll never be able to change `location` or `currentDirection`.  Instead, you'll need something like

```
data Player = Player { location :: Location
                     , direction :: Direction }
            deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
```

And then you'll want `move` to have the type

```
move :: Player -> Movement -> Player
```

The second thing to note is that you gave `move` the type `Movement -> Direction -> Location`, but you didn't actually give it a `Movement` and a `Direction` argument – you only gave it one argument, the `Movement`.  We'll instead want something like

```
move :: Player -> Movement -> Player
move p m = case m of {- ... -}
```

Note the extra `p` argument that wasn't in your code.

Now, I like the notion of using `pred` and `succ` for turning!  Unfortunately, the problem is that `pred` and `succ` will explode with an error if they overflow, rather than wrapping around, so we'll need to write our own.

```
turnRight :: Direction -> Direction
turnRight North = East
turnRight East  = South
turnRight South = West
turnRight West  = North

turnLeft :: Direction -> Direction
turnLeft North = West
turnLeft East  = North
turnLeft South = East
turnLeft West  = South
```

Here, I used "equational style", instead of `turnLeft d = case d of ...`.  It's more common, but the two are equivalent.

So, in `move`, we'd have

```
move :: Player -> Movement -> Player
move p m = case m of
  TurnLeft  -> p{direction = turnLeft  $ direction p}
  TurnRight -> p{direction = turnRight $ direction p}
  Advance   -> undefined
  BackOff   -> undefined
```

(Here, I switched back to "expression style", with `case`.  Again, same thing!)

Now, to advance and back off, I assume you're using a value `wonderland` of type `GameMap` and `filterAccess`.  `GameMap` is a bit of a suspicious type: if you want it as-is, it'd be better to use a plain triple `(Location, Direction, Location)` rather than nesting pairs.  Now, `filterAccess` is a bit dodgy as it stands because it only checks the starting location and ignores the direction.  But a better design would probably be to use a real `Map`, which would let you look up by key directly.  Make sure you add `Ord` to your derived classes for `Direction`, and then you can have

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

type GameMap = Map Location (Map Direction Location)
  -- Or `Map (Location, Direction) Location`

nextLocation :: Player -> GameMap -> Maybe Direction
nextLocation Player{location = loc, direction = dir} gmap =
  case M.lookup loc gmap of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just m' -> M.lookup dir m'
-- Or:
--     nextLocation Player{location = loc, direction = dir} gmap =
--       M.lookup dir =<< M.lookup loc gmap
```

And that should fill in the advancing case.  The backing off case will be similar, you just need to fill in the "backwards direction" logic :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have another question now. After making an instance of Player how can I print the current location and direction of the player with putStrLn?

Comment: I still have problems with Advance and BackOff. I changed type Gamemap to Map Location (Map Direction Location) but now it says that i cannot match wonderland type (Location,Direction,Location) with Map Location... Im rly confused because i dont know how Maps work

Comment: @KamilJu: If you want to stick something more like your old code, you can use a list of triples; if you want to use `Map`s, you'll have to change your code to work with them ([the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map.html) may be helpful).  Either way, if you're getting stuck, there's not really enough space in the comments to explain – figure out what the problem is and [ask a new question!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I get the impression you want to solve this yourself, but here’s a simplified toy program that might give you some ideas:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isNothing)

data Direction = North | South | East | West
  deriving Show

data WorldState = WorldState { longitude :: Integer,
                               latitude :: Integer,
                               facing :: Direction
                             }
  deriving Show

initialState :: WorldState
initialState = WorldState 0 0 West

processCommands :: WorldState ->
                   (WorldState -> String -> Maybe WorldState) ->
                   [String] ->
                   [WorldState]
{- Given an interpreter that executes commands one at a time, and a list of commands
 - to execute, return a list of the WorldState after the execution of each command.
 -}
processCommands _ _ [] = []
processCommands initial interpreter (x:xs)
  | isNothing outcome' = []
  | otherwise          = outcome:(processCommands outcome interpreter xs)
    where outcome' = interpreter initial x
          outcome = fromJust outcome'

runCommand :: WorldState -> String -> Maybe WorldState
{- Given a WorldState and a command, returns the updated WorldState, or
 - Nothing if the program is to quit.
 -}
runCommand _ "quit" = Nothing
runCommand (WorldState a b North) "left" = Just (WorldState a b West)
runCommand (WorldState a b West)  "left" = Just (WorldState a b South)
runCommand (WorldState a b South) "left" = Just (WorldState a b East)
runCommand (WorldState a b East)  "left" = Just (WorldState a b North)
runCommand (WorldState a b North) "right" = Just (WorldState a b East)
runCommand (WorldState a b East)  "right" = Just (WorldState a b South)
runCommand (WorldState a b South) "right" = Just (WorldState a b West)
runCommand (WorldState a b West)  "right" = Just (WorldState a b North)
runCommand (WorldState a b North) "forward" = Just (WorldState a (b+1) North)
runCommand (WorldState a b West)  "forward" = Just (WorldState (a-1) b West)
runCommand (WorldState a b South) "forward" = Just (WorldState a (b-1) South)
runCommand (WorldState a b East)  "forward" = Just (WorldState (a+1) b East)
runCommand (WorldState a b North) "back" = Just (WorldState a (b-1) North)
runCommand (WorldState a b West)  "back" = Just (WorldState (a+1) b West)
runCommand (WorldState a b South) "back" = Just (WorldState a (b+1) South)
runCommand (WorldState a b East)  "back" = Just (WorldState (a-1) b East)
runCommand s _ = Just s

main :: IO ()
main = interact
     ( unlines
     . map show
     . processCommands initialState runCommand
     . lines )
```

The `main` routine calls `interact`, a function that maps input to output.  Since the input and output are both read lazily, each line of input is evaluated as soon as it is entered.

The only non-functional part of the program is the call to `interact`, and in particular, you don’t need to work with monads directly.  (Although they’re nothing to be afraid of.)  Just write your pure function that transforms the input string into the output string.

So we do, in point-free style.  It splits the input into lines, and calls `processCommands` on the list of commands, one per line.

The `processCommands` function then repeatedly calls `runCommand` on each command, passing it the current state, until it says not to continue or there are no more commands.  It builds a list of each successive game state.  It is tail-recursive modulo cons, and the items of the list are consumed from left to right as soon as they are created, so this does not need to keep around any kind of state other than its parameters.  (Nor does each call to `runCommand` need any.)

This list of game states gets passed back to `main`, which turns them into printable strings with `show` and then formats them into a single output string, with the items separated by newlines.  This output string is lazily evaluated, so the program will print each state as soon as it is known.  The program thus runs interactively.

There are certainly many ways to improve this program!  I’m sure you can think of some and try them out.

For example, to check whether a direction is available, you would want to look up the position the agent is trying to get to on some kind of world map, which might be static, or passed around as part of the world state and updated.  And `processCommands` is really just one of the higher-order functions from `Data.List`.  (Which?)